# SonarQube Java plugin custom rule - deploy

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 4.2 with sonar-java-plugin-2.2.1.
I am trying to deploy a custom rule based on the BaseTreeVisitor (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/plugins/java-custom-rules/src/main/java/org/sonar/samples/java/ExampleCheck.java).

I am using gradle(not maven) to create jar (containing ExampleCheck) and than I copy this jar to sonarqube-4.2/extensions/plugins.

I expected to see ExampleCheck rule (with key nomethod)in the in/active rules after sonar will get up.

But no such rule appears. On the page http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules is nothing about deployment to the Sonarqube.

Is anything on above described deployment wrong? How to deploy ExampleCheck rule to SonarQube 4.2 ?

Comment: Finally successful sample deployment based on gradle is implemented here: https://github.com/misak69/misak69-sonar-custom

Answer (score 1):

A rule by itself will not appear, it needs to be registered by a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Mithfindel answer :

You can have a look at [JavaExtensionRuleRepository](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/plugins/java-custom-rules/src/main/java/org/sonar/samples/java/JavaExtensionRulesRepository.java) and [JavaExtensionPlugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/plugins/java-custom-rules/src/main/java/org/sonar/samples/java/JavaExtensionPlugin.java) in the github repository you mentioned to create your own plugin that will register the rules.

You would have then to deploy this plugin to see your custom rule appear.

Comment: Thx. it works! One important attention to gradle users: In the tutorial http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Coding+a+plugin about deployment is all about maven deployment, but when you create jar by gradle, don't forget customize MANIFEST.MF (see in the other plugins). Otherwise your plugin will not be found!